# Unstable behavior in Appengine LocalTaskQueueTestConfig

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit

I have a very hard time getting consistent results from LocalTaskQueueTestConfig in the AppEngine Java standard environment.  For example, running the following test in isolation

```
@Test
public void testQueueSize() throws Exception {
    Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("queue_name");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        new TaskQueueRequest("queue_name", "foo" + i).enqueue();
        System.out.println(queue.fetchStatistics().getNumTasks() + " tasks");
    }
}
```

produces

```
0 tasks
38 tasks
75 tasks
0 tasks
86 tasks
1609 tasks
775 tasks
548 tasks
1959 tasks
0 tasks
```

The actual counts vary from run to run.  Has anyone unlocked the secret to using the test framework successfully?